# MySQL - why such query works?

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table with 2 columns 
**[Col_1 and type int(11) Auto Increment]** and
**[Col_2 and type int(11) NULL]**
Let's assume in that table we have 3 rows.
 
1 7
2 7
3 6

The question is why this statement(query) is correct and why is returning such result ? 
 
 
`SELECT * from table WHERE Col_2 = '7%fdh(ds;ds)dsa'`

 
 Result:
 
1 7
 
2 7

Comment: It seems the CHAR `'7%fdh(ds;ds)dsa'` is converted to the INT `7` which is a bit a -sweep-under-the-carpet_ tactic. _I cannot believe it._ Is there an evaluation first of `%fdh(....)`?

Comment: MySQL does these liberal conversions and this often causes a lot of confusion. Not sure if there’s an option to turn this off like there are for some other things, but this is the way things work when using it. This functionality is similar to PHP where also (at least before) 7 equals “7amrjrj”

Comment: There's a warning that accompanies that query which explains what has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implicit type conversion MySQL uses when you have different types that you compare.

See [documentation about type conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) in the manual.

Quote:

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to
>   numbers as necessary, and vice versa.

Comment: Is there any way to turn this implicit conversion to off ?

Comment: @user3771470 not that i know. You should probably make sure that the types you supply to your query actually match each other. Why would you use a comparison between an integer and a string? Convert and/or check on application level